# Javascript height to impact content not just div

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a form on a webpage.  I want to have a button on a panel which when pressed expands a div (underneath the button) to make it visible and then invisible again when the button is pressed again - a kind of further details popout box.  So far i have got this:

```
function blockappear() {
    var ourblock = document.getElementById("theblock");
    ourblock.style.transition = "all 2s";
    if (ourblock.style.height == "0px") {
        ourblock.style.height = "220px";
    } else {
        ourblock.style.height = "0px";
    } 
}
```

and this:

```
#theblock {
background-color: #a83455;
height: 220px;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
display: block;
}
```

and this:

```
<p><button type="button" onclick="blockappear()">Try it</button></p>

<div id="theblock">
Some text

</div>
```

And it seems to work which is quite pleasing (even though it has taken hours to get this far).  The problem is this.  I want the div to change from 200px to 0px **including** the contents not just to the extent it can according to the contents.  At the moment the div shrinks, but the content "some text" stays put on the page.  I have tried changing the display attribute of the div to 'block' and 'table' and still no joy.  I thought that the point of a div was that it enclosed the content with the  group tags and that the content could not exist without the div.  If the div has 0px height how can the text still show?

Incidentally, if i just use display:none; on the div it works (without the transition of course).  I need the content of the div to respond to the height of the div somehow - i suspect using the css properly.

I think this has been covered before by using jquery, but i want to use javascript now that i have started as it will probably take me another few hours if i start again with a whole new language :-)

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Javascript !== Java!

Comment: OK thanks - I realise that and I don't think I say otherwise anywhere - am I in the wrong forum then?  I was careful to say that I was using javascript and that I didn't want to use Jquery - there is every chance that i have got my terms mixed up - please expand on your answer - thanks.  Incidentally, do you have an answer to my question.

Comment: Before I edited the question, its title originally said "Java", not Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to your `div`. This will hide the content which doesn't fit into the container.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use this CSS property on your div:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This will make any content of `#theblock` bigger than `#theblock` itself invisible. So - if `#theblock` has height of 0px - all of its contents will be hidden.

Default value is `overflow: visible;`, so even content bigger than containing element itself will still be there for all to see. That's all there is to it.

Read more: [overflow CSS property (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: Brilliant - thank you so much - i am a happy man (because i can go and do something else now and stop staring at this screen :-))))